# is the following method thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to know if the following method will be thread safe.

use cases : I pass two collection from different locations...

```
public static Collection<String> checkIfValidUUIDCollectionAndRefine(Collection<String> uuids){
        for(String uuid : uuids){
            if(!checkIfValidUUID(uuid)){
                uuids.remove(uuid);
            }
        }
        return uuids;
    }
```

Comment: That's not even safe in a single-thread

Comment: If each thread is gonna pass in a different collection, then there's no shared data. If there's no shared data, then it's thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` for each invalid UUID.

Second point is because of this:

```
    for(String uuid : uuids){
        if(!checkIfValidUUID(uuid)){
            uuids.remove(uuid);
        }
    }
```

The foreach loop creates an iterator internally, but you modifiy this iterator. You have to create an iterator and use `.remove()`.

For instance:

```
final Iterator<String> iterator = uuids.iterator();
String uuid;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    uuid = iterator.next();
    if (!checkIfValidUUID(uuid))
        iterator.remove();
}
return uuids;
```

Comment: The second point means it won't work even if there's only one thread.

Comment: The first point isn't really conclusive - there's nothing *inherently* thread-unsafe about this, if the two collections used in different threads are different collections. And the caller *cannot* modify it while the method runs... they're waiting for the method to finish! Another thread might be modifying the collection, but the caller definitely won't be doing so.

Comment: And the "take a copy" idea doesn't really work either - if another thread *is* modifying the collection, then that will fail while you're taking a copy. Basically you'd need to either use a concurrent collection, or use synchronization (in both threads). But again, I wouldn't say this thread is inherently "not thread safe" - it doesn't do anything non-thread-safe *in itself*. It's just that you'd need to be careful not to call it with a collection shared between threads.

Comment: @all : the following method is called from the spring controller and the collections passed are not shared.

Comment: @JonSkeet text fixed; and yeah, the copy doesn't work either. This is why I always use Guava's`Immutable*` when I can...

Answer (score -1):

You need to make it `synchronized` to make it `thread` safe. Then you need use the `Iterator` to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: There is no need for synchronization, this method does not share mutable state with other threads.

Comment: @bowmore What if two threads are calling the method with same `uuids`?